# Limit 100 requests per min setup in Jmeter is not working

Tags: rest, python-requests, jmeter

I have tried couple of suggestions as mentioned in other sites on how to configure/Limit 100 requests per minute for a given REST endpoint for a single user. its not working !

Can someone please guide me to setup on how to limit a 100 requests for a given REST endpoint?

Thankyou in Advance!!

Comment: Can you provide more information about what have you already tried?

Comment: In JMETER , Under the Thread group I have added a "constant throughput timer". value set for the target throughput(samples per min) is 100 and added HTTP requests.  I am not sure does this setups yields accurate results what I'm expecting. i want to limit the 'N' number of requests for a min for a given endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is adding [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) however be aware that it's precise enough on **minute** level so you will have to let your test to run for at least a minute before you start seeing the rate limiting, if your test throughput is higher during the first minute - consider playing with ramp-up.

If you have only 1 user and your test runs for a minute or less you will have to consider the following options:

- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin)

the latter one is extremely easy to use and it provides visual way of defining the target throughput:

[image]